# AppData\Roaming folder in windows service project

Tags: windows, windows-services

I need a help on getting Special folder in windows service program. I used this code in my *Windows Form* application:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

and got the path, ""C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming"*

But if I run the same code in my *Winows Service* project I got the path: *"C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Roaming\"*

But I need the earlier path (got in *Windows Form*). How do I get the same path in Service projet also.

I have user setting file, log, config file in the *"C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming"* folder. So I have to refer the same path both in my *Windows Form* application and *Windows Service* project.

Can somebody tell me, what is the difference here and how do i get the same path in both type of project?

Thanks,
sharath

Answer (score 3):

Your Windows Service should use 'User' Account, instead of 'LocalService' or 'LocalSystem'.

```
        ServiceProcessInstaller process = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
        process.Account = ServiceAccount.User;
```

And during installation of the service, you need to specify the username and password of currently logged in user. Username should be in this format: "MachineName\UserName". Example: ".\John"