# Windows background service (system profile) is UNABLE to access user appData folder on win 10 using C++?

Tags: c++, windows, service

Wondering if Windows background service (system profile) is UNABLE to access user appData folder on win 10 using C++ ?
It seems Windows service does not load user profile by default as links below and wondering if it is same as win 10.

- [.net windows service local application data is different then in normal app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247581/net-windows-service-local-application-data-is-different-then-in-normal-app)
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/0e8892b2-a9ce-446d-a8ee-c37c0a217ddd/not-able-to-get-user-s-app-data-folder-when-using-windows-service?forum=winforms
- [AppData\Roaming folder in windows service project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273674/appdata-roaming-folder-in-windows-service-project)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `SYSTEM` account has full access to the local machine, so of course it can access any user's AppData folder. The trick will be in obtaining the path to a given user's AppData folder in the first place.

APIs exist for the very purpose of obtaining user-related folder paths, see `SHGetFolderPath()` and `SHGetKnownFolderPath()`, both of which take a user token as input.  Services run in a separate session from users, and the `SYSTEM` account has its own profile in the Registry, so you can't use anything that depends on `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` of the calling process to query the paths, as it will query the `SYSTEM`'s paths, not a user's paths.  You need to obtain the token of the desired user you want to query.

If the target user is logged in, you can use `WTSQueryUserToken()` to get the user's token.  You just need the user's session ID, which you can get from `ProcessIdToSessionId()` for any process running on the user's session, or you can use `WTSEnumerateSessions()` and `WTSQuerySessionInformation()` to find the session containing the desired user's login info (if there is more than 1 user logged in), or you can use `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()` to get the session that is logged in and currently attached to the physical keyboard/mouse/monitor.

If the target user is not logged in, but you have the user's credentials, you can use `LogonUser()` to get the user's token.  You can then use `LoadUserProfile()` to access the user's `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` Registry hive and query the `"\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"` subkey directly.

Otherwise, you are pretty such SOL, unless you happen to know the user's SID, in which case you can enumerate the `HKEY_USERS` Registry hive looking for that SID, and then you can query the `"\<SID>\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"` subkey directly.

Comment: I believe windows service use localService not  SYSTEM account and I need to get logged user's appData folder using windows service

Comment: Windows services can be configured to use whichever account you want, including `SYSTEM` which is, in fact, the default account used if you do not specify an account. You can make a service use `LocalService` instead, but you have to setup that explicitly. `SYSTEM` (aka `LocalSystem`) and `LocalService` are separate accounts. But either way, regardless of which account the service is *running* as, it is possible to access a particular user's AppData path with some work. Since the user you want is logged in, you just need the user's token, which `LocalSystem` can get via `WTSQueryUserToken()`..

Comment: But if your service is not running as `LocalSystem`, then you can't use `WTSQueryUserToken()`, so getting the user token takes more work. For instance, by finding the user's session and then extracting the token from a process running in that session, like `explorer.exe`.